# XCODE 8.0 quits unexpectedly

Tags: xcode8

Everytime I open my project in xcode 8.0 it quits unexpectedly as soon as I press any key for coding in view controller swift file and when i again open xcode my project is started automatically and again the problem persists. Please help me in solving this issue.

when i open viewconroller.swift file or any other swift file in any project it simply exits xcode and the error message "xcode quits Unexpectedly" arrives. attached image of error. my project type is ios application, working in os sierra version 10.12.2
 and in xcode 8.0

Comment: Please provide more detail about your problem, e,g XCode, OS, Project Type, Error Message for Console ...

Comment: please check i have described my question in detail

Comment: The current version of Xcode 8.2.1. Please update to that, or to the beta of 8.3.

Comment: yes but can u please help me with this issue for xcode 8.0 because my project is already made in xcode 8 and if i upgrade now than i have to make  changes in my code.

Comment: What do you mean by 'press any key for coding' ?

Do you mean that the project loads, and displays, but crashes when you start editing it?

Does it happen with one particular file?

Do other projects / new projects work OK?

Comment: yes as soon as  i start editing in my swift file xcode crashes

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally get this problem -  if you clear out the DerivedData folders you should be sorted.

The DerivedData folders should be in your user

```
/CurrentUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

you can search for DerivedData if it's not there.

Delete those folders, and redstart your project.  It will take a little while, depending on the size of the project to reindex, but you should be able to continue development.

Comment: i have cleared the derived data folders but still the same problem exists

Answer (score 0):

Facing same problem sometimes - there is two way to solve this issue.

1)

Follow the screen shot.
Follow 4 steps that highlighted in photo and remove derived data then restart your project.

[image: Follow 4 steps that highlighted in photo and remove derived data then restart your project.]

2)
if first salutation is not worked then uninstall your Xcode and reinstall it will works.

Thanks, Good Luck.